# Como montar um servidor para autenticação de cliente

Tags: java, cliente-servidor

Tenho uma aplicação em java, e gostaria de ter um servidor on-line para autenticação dos clientes offline.

Exemplo: O cliente x precisaria conectar ao menos uma vez no servidor, para se autenticar antes que o cliente seja bloqueado.

Gostaria de algum exemplo de tipos de servidor que poderia criar e como montar a estrutura pra isso.

Comment: Olá! Achei a pergunta um pouco difícil de entender, tem como explicar melhor? Como assim servidor online para autenticação offline? Não entendi =)

Comment: Peço desculpas pela pergunta, realmente ta complicada. O que queria fazer um servidor onde minha aplicação fizesse login para conseguir autenticar. Ficaria para termos controle dos clientes que pagam aluguel do sistema.